# ,net core 3.1 AddAuthorization method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm migrating from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 but I got this error in runtime

System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AuthorizationServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthorization(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationOptions>)'.'

I made sure that I include all the needed nuget libraries

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0-preview.2.21154.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Signed.IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection" Version="3.5.0" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="5.0.0" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I even tried adding ( not convinced it's needed)

and in startup

```
 services.AddMvc(options => {
                options.AddOAuth2AuthorizationPolicy(); 
            });
services.AddAuthorization();
```

not sure what's missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy or use AddAuthorizationCore instead. The change is described in [ASP.NET Core breaking changes for versions 3.0 and 3.1 list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#authorization-addauthorization-overload-moved-to-different-assembly), quote:

> The core AddAuthorization methods that used to reside in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization were renamed to
> AddAuthorizationCore. The old AddAuthorization methods still exist,
> but are in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy assembly
> instead.

Comment: Do note that it's also not a package anymore, as described in the same [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#shared-framework-assemblies-removed-from-microsoftaspnetcoreapp). The changes needed are also described there.